# How to use rxjs takeWhile operator with apollo-client watchQuery?

Tags: rxjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, svelte

I have a Svelte application where I use `watchQuery` to subscribe to a query. I want to use `takeWhile` operator from rxjs along with it but I get this error:

`TypeError: $client.watchQuery(...).takeWhile is not a function`

Is there a way I can use `takeWhile` with `apollo-client`'s `watchQuery` subscription?

This is my code:

```
$client.watchQuery({
  query: SomeRandomQuery,
  variables: {},
})
.pipe(takeWhile(() => isAlive))
.subscribe(res => {
 ...
});
```

I also tried removing the `pipe()` and passing it directly but get the same error.

```
$client.watchQuery({
  query: SomeRandomQuery,
  variables: {},
})
.takeWhile(() => isAlive)
.subscribe(res => {
 ...
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with a takeUntil

```
const finalise = new Subject();

$client.watchQuery({
  query: SomeRandomQuery,
  variables: {},
})
.pipe(takeUntil(finalise))
.subscribe(res => {
 ...
});
```

Now when you want to finalise the observable you call next on the subject.

```
finalise.next();
finalise.complete();
```

This is the established pattern we use in Angular components where a single subject can finalise all the observable chains in a single onDestroy method.

The advantage of this is finalise is an observable and will trigger the takeUntil when it emits, take and takeWhile don't take observables as their parameters and will remain subscribed until the observable emits which leads to orphan subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am familiar with the above pattern and even tried it but the problem is I can't chain `.pipe()` or `takeUnit` or `takeWhile` with the watchQuery subscription like we do in Angular. It still throws the same error - 
```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $client.watchQuery(...).pipe is not a function```
I am initialising `ApolloClient` from `apollo-boost` in the `$client` const. I'm using this setup in a Svelte 3 app.

Comment: What version of RxJs are you using? pipe is not a function means watchQuery does not return an observable or you are on RxJs version 5. I am not familiar with Svelte so not sure what $client.watchQuery does.

Comment: I just Googled it and watchQuery returns an ObservableQuery object, it does not look like it is an RxJs Observable from the quick read I did.

Comment: The valueChanges property on an ObservableQuery is an Observable.

Comment: Its very strange, the `valueChanges` property is undefined. Getting
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`
if I use 
```$client.watchQuery({... }).valueChanges.subscribe(res => {```. 
Any pointers on this?

Comment: Thank you for your kind response Adrian! With my primary objective to destroy subscriptions in an `onDestroy` lifecycle hook (and a tight deadline), I managed to do this without using `rxjs` -  
```const querySubscription = $client.watchQuery({... }).valueChanges.subscribe(...);``` then called ```querySubscription.unsubscribe()``` in `onDestroy()`. There are still a few things that didn't make sense like why `valueChanges` property is not available on `watchQuery` and I'll post it here if I come across it.